# How to get what record was affected by mysql query? (second record, third record or tenth record)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, record

$this->db->affected_rows()

Displays the number of affected rows, when doing "write" type queries (insert, update, etc.).

If there is 3 record affected how to get order of that record. Thanks

Comment: First of all update your question with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.

Generally speaking, in PHP, the only possible way is to **run another query** to get these rows. There might be a function to get **number** of affected row, but not the rows themselves.

```
$this->db->query($q);
$this->db->affected_rows();// will return "number" of affected rows.
```

Note: As @ArunVitto mentioned, if none of the values changed in the row(s), it will not be counted by the `affected_rows()`.

So, this is how you suppose to do it:

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE `users` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `first_name`="Eko"');
$total = $this->db->affected_rows();// $total is number of affected rows
$result = $this->db->query('SELECT * from `users` WHERE `first_name`="Eko"');
$users = $result->result_array();// The rows after being update
```